# Can I win anything from the eShop roulette wheel?

Tags: wii-u

The Wii U eShop now has a roulette wheel on the loading screen. Is it possible to win anything from it, or is it just for fun?

Comment: What a co-inky-dink! I asked myself this same question yesterday... :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roulette's sole purpose is to give you something to do while the eShop loads. There are no prizes to be earned.